# Python Discord - How to get the initial joined date for a member in a specific server?

Tags: python, discord

For the past few months I have been working on a discord bot in a server I am moderating. I started with no experience in discord bots so I chose python over javascript when I started with my bot. I am rather familiar with the discord library in python and have been able to use it for almost everything that has been needed so far.

I am in a need to get the date when a user joined my server for the first time.
In the documentation it states:

> joined_at: A datetime object that specifies the date and time in UTC that the member joined the guild. **If the member left and rejoined the guild, this will be the latest date**.

I am wondering if it is at all possible to get the date when a user joined a server for the first time using the pythons discord library? Is discord even keeping track of this?
It would be really nice, if I could get this information without having to log it on my own.

**ANSWER**

The discord is not keeping track of all the dates when users join a discord server, but only the last one, so if I would want to find out the first time a user joined the server, I would need to save this data in a database or a some sort of a storage file (for example, json file) every time a new user joins.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using discord py isn't keeping the first joined date.
However, you can save the first joined date within a dictionary or a database.

> Example for saving in a dictionary

```py
def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client
    self.first_join = {}

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_join(self, member):
    if member in first_join:
        return

    self.first_join[member.id] = member.joined_at
```

Comment: I'd recommend using something more reliable like backing up self.first_join in a file or database every once in a while and loading it when the bot is initialized again, because it would reset every time you restarted the bot, but this works as a concept.

Comment: heh, was wondering the same. Would the dictionary not reset every time the bot gets restarted? It is a shame discord is not keeping track of that, although, it is understandable. I will then go with either a json file or a database. Thanks guys!

Comment: @duhby just gave the simpler answer, but yes, saving to a database would be better. However this open the door to a infinite possibilities of answer example, which is why i don't put it.